# Case Insensitive Search parameters for API endpoint

Tags: regex, string-matching

I am working on a project that involves integrating the PUBG API. From my site, the player can lookup stats using their player name, platform and season. One issue I am facing is that the player name have to be exact and is case sensitive. Now I assumed it to be the case at the beginning. However, after searching for the name in [this site](https://pubg.op.gg/user/mYCHoLula) I found that they don't need the name to be case sensitive. Also, referring to this post from the PUBG Dev community [here](https://forums.pubg.com/topic/329444-caps-sensitive/) I saw that it confirmed my initial assumption. So my question is if PUBG API requires the names to be case sensitive then, how is the site (linked) can search for the player even if the name provided is not in exact, matching case? For example,:

I looked up the player name MyCholula. From the PUBG API page for player lookup, it returns the proper value. When I tried mycholula, it doesn't and sends a 404. From the linked site above, both combination seems to work. Now if spaces or other separators were involved in the name then, it would be easy to convert it assuming that separated words are all capitalized (somewhat naive assumption though). For this name, I don't see any way of converting mycholula to MyCholula. I also tried many other combination in the linked site above (also different user names I got from my friends) to confirm that the linked site is actually returning the data as expected for any combination of user names. I also tried it on other sites like [this](https://pubglookup.com/search) and it didn't work just like it doesn't work from the PUBG DEV API page or from my page.

I am really confused as to how they are doing it. The only possible explanation I can come up with is that they have the player records stored in their database from where, they can perform advanced regexp based search to get the actual name. However, this sounds far fetched since, there are millions of players and it would require them to know all the player names and associated IDs. Also, as far as I know, it is not possible to use regex or other string manipulation to convert to the actual name because there can be many combinations (not an expert on regex so can't be definitive on this).

Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Unless you have confirmed otherwise, it seems the public facing website is not necessarily using the API.

Comment: @varontron That thought crossed my mind too but I didn't find any reference yet to suggest this. I'll dig more into it.